# datatype equivalent to sysname in SSIS

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I was trying to add variables with data types sysname in SSIS. But the data type list does not show the option of sysname. If anyone have idea on it. It has object data type. Will I be able to use it? If not, what the data type would be. Thank you.

For example,
in SQL, I have declaration of variable like @tableName sysname

Comment: `sysname` is equivalent to `nvarchar(128)` in all current versions of SQL Server so you can just treat it as that

Comment: Yes, but I do not have option to choose nvarchar(128) in SSIS. That's why I am trying to figure out what it should be. There is object data type and I am trying to find if it is same. @MartinSmith

Comment: Your SSIS variable can just be String. SSIS data types can be confusing, and depending on exactly what you are doing with the variable, it probably important to know what the SSIS Expression data type (DT_WSTR, 128) is equivalent to nvarchar(128). For more detail about SSIS to SQL Server data type, see this: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/dknight/2010/12/22/ssis-to-sql-server-data-type-translations/